# missing secret file after install varnish3 by homebrew on mac

Tags: homebrew, varnish

everyone

I install varnish3 on mac 10.8.3 by homebrew, and it works.
but i try to find secret file for varnish, can't find it at /usr/local/etc/varnish and /usr/local/Cellar/varnish/3.0.3/. 
who can tell me where is this secret file for varnish? totally get confuse for it. please help me thanks. 
this is really strange for me. in drupal7 after install varnish module will need use this secret file key for connect backend server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your Varnish started with secret key?
Check `ps ax | grep varnish`
output should contain something like `-S /usr/local/etc/varnish/secret`

If you don't see it, then you may skip this field in Drupal, else you will be able to check file contents (or modify)

Comment: i can sure there no /usr/local/etc/varnish/secret, and i reinstall varnish with brew, still not find it. in drupal i skip that field but showing not connect to varnish server~~~~

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Not sure how one would add a secret key with homebrew. Maybe you can't.